An error while using tensorflowjs with NextJs

ModelLoader.js:17 Error loading model: ValueError: An InputLayer should be passed either a batchInputShape or an inputShape.

The above error is encountered when I am running a simple shelf life prediction trained using tensor flow and used as JSON file in my next app.
my model.json file and the .bin file is located in the "public/model/" directory.
I am not sure if the issue is with the way that i have trained my model.
I am new to ML.
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np 
from datetime import datetime

# Load your dataset
data = pd.read_csv("./syntheticdataset.csv")

# Drop item_id and batch_number as they're not useful for prediction
data = data.drop(['item_id', 'batch_number'], axis=1)

# Convert date columns to numerical (days since production or expiry)
reference_date = datetime(2024, 1, 1)

# Convert date_of_production and expiry_date to datetime
data['date_of_production'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_of_production'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
data['expiry_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['expiry_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

# Calculate days since the reference date for both columns
data['days_since_production'] = (data['date_of_production'] - reference_date).dt.days
data['days_until_expiry'] = (data['expiry_date'] - reference_date).dt.days

# Drop the original date columns
data = data.drop(['date_of_production', 'expiry_date'], axis=1)

# Convert categorical columns into numerical using OneHotEncoding
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False)
encoded_columns = encoder.fit_transform(data[['item_name', 'storage_type']])

# Convert to DataFrame
encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(encoded_columns, columns=encoder.get_feature_names_out())

# Reset index to avoid alignment issues
encoded_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Drop categorical columns and concatenate encoded columns
data = data.drop(['item_name', 'storage_type'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
data = pd.concat([data, encoded_df], axis=1)

# Split data into features (X) and target (y)
X = data.drop('shelf_life_days', axis=1)
y = data['shelf_life_days']

# Standardize the numerical features (temperature, humidity)
scaler = StandardScaler()
X[['temperature', 'humidity']] = scaler.fit_transform(X[['temperature', 'humidity']])

# Split the data into training and testing sets (80-20 split)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Build the model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))  # Define input shape explicitly
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))  # 1st hidden layer
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))  # 2nd hidden layer
model.add(layers.Dense(1))  # Output layer for regression

# Compile the model with optimizer, loss function, and metrics
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])

# Train the model (epochs and batch size can be adjusted)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

# Print the final training and validation metrics
print("Final Training MAE:", history.history['mae'][-1])
print("Final Validation MAE:", history.history['val_mae'][-1])

# Save the model with the input shape explicitly defined
model.save('model2.h5')  # Save in HDF5 format
 

React code:
// components/ModelLoader.js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import React from 'react';
const ModelLoader = () => {
  const [model, setModel] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadModel = async () => {
      try {
        // Load the model from the public/model/ directory
        const loadedModel = await tf.loadLayersModel('/model/model.json');
        console.log(loadedModel.inputs[0].shape)
        setModel(loadedModel);
        console.log('Model loaded successfully:', loadedModel);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error loading model:', error);
      }
    }
    
    loadModel();
  }, [model]);
  
  console.log(model)
  return (
    <div>
      {model ? <p>Model loaded!</p> : <p>Loading model...</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ModelLoader;

